# Using a Meteor Subscription handle's .ready() function as a reactive source when Subscription is in a Deps.autorun

Tags: javascript, meteor, publish-subscribe, reactive-programming

So I have a subscription in a Deps.autorun and I want to keep track of when the subscription is still loading documents and when it has finished or "ready."

I want to use the .ready() function on the handle that is returned by the Meteor.Subscribe method as a reactive data source in a handlebars helper. This works fine for the first subscription. But when the Deps is invalidated and the subscription is re-run, the handlebars template is not re-run.

I assume this is because the .ready() on the subscription handle is not getting in-validated. In other words the dependency created for the handlebars helper is on the old .ready() reactive element and when the Deps.autorun is re-run and the subscription re-set there is a new handle and the handlebars helper isn't dependent on this new .ready() function.

My workaround is to create a session variable within the Deps.autorun set to false, then pass an onReady callback function to the subscription which sets that session variable to true.

Here is my original code which only works for the first subscription.

```
var searchResultsHandle = null;

Deps.autorun(function () {
    searchResultsHandle = Meteor.subscribe("searchResults", Session.get('searchQuery'));
});

Handlebars.registerHelper("searchResultsLoaded", function() {
    return searchResultsHandle && searchResultsHandle.ready();
});
```

And my workaround:

```
var searchResultsHandle = null;

Deps.autorun(function () {
    Session.set('searchResultsLoaded', false);
    searchResultsHandle = Meteor.subscribe("searchResults", Session.get('searchQuery'), function(){
        Session.set('searchResultsLoaded', true);
    });
});

Handlebars.registerHelper("searchResultsLoaded", function() {
    return Session.equals('searchResultsLoaded', true);
});
```

Is that the right way to solve the issue? Is there any way to still use the .ready() function as a reactive datasource and re-subscribe in this way?

Comment: Are you sure you really want to resubscribe? That eliminates the benefit of Meteor's latency compensation.

Comment: Well for the search use case, I would actually use a Meteor.call RPC method call. This is just an example of an issue I've found when re-subscribing inside of a Deps.autorun. There are lots of cases where I would want to re-subscribe reactively like this. For example if I had a chat room and I wanted to change which room I am subscribed to.

I'm curious what you mean by eliminating the latency compensation benefit. I can still do inserts and updates and removes on this collection and get the same latency compensation that I would expect.

Comment: Okay, I re-read your code and I see what you're doing. Yes, I think your solution makes the most sense. You can't use the `.ready()` function as a reactive data source for *every subscription*, because each subscription is returning a brand new handler with its own `.ready()` function. The only thing I would change is in your helper, you can just use `return Session.get("searchResultsLoaded");`, because you only ever set it to a boolean value.

Comment: Actually, shouldn't you be able to create a local collection with the same name as your published collection and use its `.observe()` function as the reactive data source for your helper function?